# Why am I getting undefined in my typeahead results?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, typeahead, bloodhound

I am trying to get this typeahead working with an ajax call and I'm close but stuck.

Currently, it is returning a list of 5 "undefined" items in the dropdown. I have tried formatting my ajax response both as an array and as json encoded.

I have tested my php resource that is responding to the ajax call and when I load this uri:

```
/search?searchField=apple
```

with a search term in my browser I get the correct results in the following format:

```
["Apple American Group","Apple Financial Holdings Inc","Apple Inc","Appleton Coated LLC","Appleton Inc","Appleton Papers Inc","Dr Pepper Snapple Group Inc","Maui Land & Pineapple Co Inc","Red Apple Group Inc"]
```

I can see from my console output that the ajax call is being triggered and successful:

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://cha.dev:8000/search?searchField=a". jquery.js:9631
send jquery.js:9631
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:9176
b.mixin._get typeahead.bundle.min.js:7
f
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" id="bloodhound">
<input type="text" name="searchField" class="form-control typeahead" id="searchId" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off">
</div>

<!-- just before close of body tag -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var businesses = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'search?searchField=%QUERY'
});

businesses.initialize();

$('#searchId').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'businessList',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: businesses.ttAdapter()
});
```

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: When I add the curly braces the drop down results don't appear at all. When I load that in my browser I get a header along with the data, that says it's Content-Type: application/json.

Comment: {["Apple Inc", "Appleton Inc", "etc"]}

Answer (score 0):

The *key* is the important part of the JSON being returned. The example below uses `business` as the *key*.

Javascript:

```
var businesses = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('business'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: 'search?searchField=%QUERY'
});

businesses.initialize();

$('#searchId').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'businessList',
    displayKey: 'business',
    source: businesses.ttAdapter()
});
```

Data that should be returned:

```
[ { "business": "Apple American Group"},
  { "business": "Apple Financial Holdings Inc"},
  { "business": "Apple Inc"},
  { "business": "Appleton Coated LLC"},
  { "business": "Appleton Inc"},
  { "business": "Appleton Papers Inc"},
  { "business": "Dr Pepper Snapple Group Inc"},
  { "business": "Maui Land & Pineapple Co Inc"},
  { "business": "Red Apple Group Inc"} ]
```